# Hungarian Algorithm Constraint using Python

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, hungarian-algorithm

I have dataframe of job and employee, with the duration each employee can finish each job.
I want to use Hungarian algorithm to assign each job to 1 employee, and each employee can only assigned by 1 job.

Here is the data:

```
    J1   J2   J3
E1  3    5    2
E2  7    3    9
E3  4    2    7
E4  2    7    5
E5  6    8    8
```

The expected result was:

```
    J1   J2   J3
E1  0    0    1
E2  0    0    0
E3  0    1    0
E4  1    0    0
E5  0    0    0
```

And then print out this:

```
Job   Employee
 1       4
 2       3
 3       1
```

Can anyone help me on this matter? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `df` the input dataframe, you can use [`scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html):

```
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
x,y = linear_sum_assignment(df)
out = pd.DataFrame({'Job': df.columns[y], 'Employee': df.index[x]})
```

output:

```
  Job Employee
0  J3       E1
1  J2       E3
2  J1       E4
```